# How do you disable message preview in the Android 4.0.x stock email app?

Tags: email

How do you disable message preview in the Android 4.0.x stock email app?  The only message preview options are "Small", "Medium" and "Large".

(Android 4.0.4 on a Droid Bionic.)

Comment: Its unlikely there is a way to do this if there isn't an option to disable it.  You would have to use a client that does offer the option to disable message preview if you wanted to disable message preview.

Comment: @Ramhound - Well that stinks.  If you put this as an answer I will select it as best answer, because my gut says you are right.